# Showing different content per user

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I want to write my first hangout app. (a simple card game). According to the documentation the correct application type would be "main application" which shows the content in the main window.

My problem is now that all users see the same content. Each user should see "his" cards only.

Is there a way to have different content per user? The doc mentions a "shared state" for global application settings but I need to use local information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself:
Each client creates his own instance of the JS-File that is used. So inside that JS-Object everything is just local.

To exchange these local informations the shared state has to be used.